# How to tell RecyclerView to start at specific item position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, position

I want my RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager to show up with scroll position at specific item after adapter got updated. (not first/last position)
Means the at first (re-)layout, this given position should be in visible area.
It should not layout with position 0 on top and scroll afterwards to target position.

My Adapter starts with itemCount=0, loads its data in thread and notifies its real count later. But the start position must be set already while count is still 0!

As of now I used some kind of `post Runnable` containing`scrollToPosition` but this has side effects (starts at first pos and jumps immediately to target position  (0 -> target) and seems not to work well with DiffUtil (0 -> target -> 0))

**Edit:** To clearify: I need alternative to `layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);`, something like `setStackFrom(position)`. ScrollToPosition does not work, if I call it when itemCount is still 0, so it gets ignored. If I call it when I notify that itemCount is now >0, it will layout from 0 and jumps short after to target position. And it fails completely if I use DiffUtil.DiffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(adapter)`. (shows from 0, then scrolls to target position and then again back to position 0)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a solution myself:

I extended the LayoutManager:

```
  class MyLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    private int mPendingTargetPos = -1;
    private int mPendingPosOffset = -1;

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChildren(Recycler recycler, State state) {
        if (mPendingTargetPos != -1 && state.getItemCount() > 0) {
            /*
            Data is present now, we can set the real scroll position
            */
            scrollToPositionWithOffset(mPendingTargetPos, mPendingPosOffset);
            mPendingTargetPos = -1;
            mPendingPosOffset = -1;
        }
        super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        /*
        May be needed depending on your implementation.

        Ignore target start position if InstanceState is available (page existed before already, keep position that user scrolled to)
         */
        mPendingTargetPos = -1;
        mPendingPosOffset = -1;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }

    /**
     * Sets a start position that will be used <b>as soon as data is available</b>.
     * May be used if your Adapter starts with itemCount=0 (async data loading) but you need to
     * set the start position already at this time. As soon as itemCount > 0,
     * it will set the scrollPosition, so that given itemPosition is visible.
     * @param position
     * @param offset
     */
    public void setTargetStartPos(int position, int offset) {
        mPendingTargetPos = position;
        mPendingPosOffset = offset;
    }
}
```

It stores my target position. If `onLayoutChildren` is called by RecyclerView, it checks if adapters itemCount is already > 0. If true, it calls `scrollToPositionWithOffset()`.

So I can tell immediately what position should be visible, but it will not be told to  LayoutManager before position exists in Adapter.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this, it will scroll to a position you want:

```
rv.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(positionInTheAdapter).
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not match the described szenario.

Comment: that works after everything gets laid out, but it won't work if its call when you are setting the view. the recyclerview set up isn't far enough along to execute it correctly, and it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll to a specific position and that position is the adapter's position, then you can use  `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` `scrollToPosition`

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
       staggeredGridLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(10);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
```

If I understand the question, you want to scroll to a specific position but that position is the adapter's position and not the RecyclerView's item position.

You can only achieve this through the `LayoutManager`.

```
rv.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(youPositionInTheAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to scroll, I want to **start** at myPosition as soon this position is available in adapter.

Comment: So, You need to set the position which you want. @allofmex

Comment: But at the time I need to set the position, this position does not yet exist in adapter. (but I know it will exists soon when data loading finished)

Comment: So, my suggestion is that when your data completely get loaded till then you can show loading view, after then set the scroll to position.

Answer (score 0):

None of the methods above worked for me. I did the following using ViewTreeObserver that is triggered once its children have been added/changed visibility.

```
recyclerView.apply {
   adapter = ...
   layoutManager = ...

   val itemCount = adapter?.itemCount ?: 0
   if(itemCount > 1) {
      viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object: ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
      override fun onGlobalLayout() {
         viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
         (layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager)?.scrollToPosition(#PositionToStartAt)
      }
   }
}
```

Go ahead and set #PositionToStartAt to a specific value. You can also ensure that the RecyclerView initial position setting gets triggered once a specific number of children have been laid out to ensure it is set correctly.

```
if(recyclerView.childCount() > #PositionCheck) {
   viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
   (layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager)?.scrollToPosition(#PositionToStartAt)
}
```

Comment: But this will again layout once at wrong position (position 0) and scroll afterwards to target position. What I want is to have the correct position right away on first (child)layout!

Comment: You can't scroll to a child or position that doesn't exist yet... It's like attempting to retrieve position 2 in an array that is empty. I would say you can make your RecyclerView Invisible with View.INVISIBLE, trigger the scroll, and View.VISIBLE. If you want it to be elegant, you can ALPHA = 0f instead, and animate it with a Fade to ALPHA = 1f.

Answer (score 0):

If your only motive is to start the recyclerView from a specific position without any **scroll-like animation** I'll suggest using **StaggeredGridLayoutManager**

```
val staggeredGridLayoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL)//or VERTICAL
            staggeredGridLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(specificPosition)

recyclerView.apply{
    layoutManager = staggeredGridLayoutManager
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another contribution to a long running question...

As mentioned, `layoutManager.scrollToPosition/WithOffset()` does work to get the RecyclerView positioned, but timing this can be tricky.  For example with variable length item views the RecyclerView has to work hard to get all the prior item views measured.

The approach below simply delays telling the RecyclerView about the prior items, then calls `notifyItemRangeInserted(0, offset)`.  This enabled the view to appear in the right place, with no visible scrolling at the start, and ready to scroll back.

```
private List<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();

...

private class ViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    private volatile int offset;
    private boolean offsetCancelled;

    ViewAdapter(int initialOffset) {
        this.offset = initialOffset;
        this.offsetCancelled = initialOffset > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bitmaps.size() - offset;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MyActivity.this);  // Or getContext() from a Fragment

        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        return new ViewHolder(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(position + offset));

        if (!offsetCancelled) {
            offsetCancelled = true;
            recyclerView.post(() -> {
                int previousOffset = offset;
                offset = 0;
                notifyItemRangeInserted(0, previousOffset);
                Log.i(TAG, "notifyItemRangeInserted(0, " + previousOffset + ")");
            });
        }
    }
}

private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final ImageView imageView;

    ViewHolder(@NonNull ImageView itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.imageView = itemView;
    }
}
```

For context, this is a full example, based around ImageView's and Bitmap's.  The key bit is the use of the offset in `getItemCount()` and `onBindViewHolder()`.